# C# how to load a form with marquee progress bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, marquee

I created a loadingForm with only a progress bar with marquee style. In my mainForm I'm trying to do this:

```
//before downloading
loadingForm lf = new loadingForm();
lf.Show();
//start downloading
//finishdownloading
lf.Close();
```

The loadingForm was shown but the progress bar didn't appear, and the form looked like it was crash. after finishing downloading, the loadingForm was closed and my app continued to run normally. In loadingForm I only have:

```
void loadingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     progressbar1.visible = true;
}
```

I already set progressbar1 style to marquee in loadingForm.design. How do I fix this? thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do *not* block after the lf.Show() call.  Use the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted event to call lp.Close()

Comment: sorry but could you explain your answer? I'm kinda new to programming. What you mean by do not block? And how do I use the BackgroundWoker.RunWorkerCompleted to call the lf.Close? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at using [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for the time consuming actions, so that the UI can continue showing the progress while the background worker thread does the work.

- [How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [BackgroundWorker Basics in C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c%23/)
- [C# BackgroundWorker Tutorial](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Comment: Could I use background Worker on the form loading? because in my mainForm I already put the downloading actions in other thread. (I start a new thread for each downloading from server to client, my mainForm is in client application).

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the download and the form with the progress bar are run on the same thread. You could use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to perform the download in a different thread than the form.

Comment: thanks for your answer. As I ask astander in the comment, could I load new form on a different thread instead? because my mainForm kinda complicated about threading already with creating new thread with each connection between client and server.

Comment: Yes you can create the a form on a new thread.  You will have to make sure that there is a message loop running by either calling Application.Run or use ShowDialog() in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

The UI thread might not have "resources" to redraw the ui, you should use the background worker as mentioned, or process the application messages in the queue. From the Show() method to the Close() method you should be sure to call Application.DoEvents(), so all windows messages will be processed (along with redrawing messages to your application form)