# how to implement progress bar in window form

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, progress

I have a problem regarding window form progress bar. I have a progress bar in a windows application using c#, Now i want to show a progress bar on button click, but the condition is when button is clicked a update query will be executed it will take 30 seconds to complete, I want to show progress bar while the query is executed. I'm trying little bit code but not find solution for it.

c#

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This will update your Website. " + Environment.NewLine + "Are you Sure You want to update the Website?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                pgbrUpdate.Visible = true;
                pgbrUpdate.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
                ExecuteQuerry();
                pgbrUpdate.Visible = false;
            }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# how to load a form with marquee progress bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499561/c-sharp-how-to-load-a-form-with-marquee-progress-bar)

Comment: You should probably build a background worker to update the progress bar during the execution of your query, when the progress bar is fileed and the query finishes you can then disable the bar

Comment: Check the link which @DanielKelley has shared, it references to some documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

Move the UpdateTask to a new task (or thread) and show some progress with a Timer:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This will update your Website. " + 
       Environment.NewLine + "Are you Sure You want to update the Website?", 
       "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
         updateTimer.Start();
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteQuery());
    }
}

updateTimer_Tick()
{
   updateTimer.Value +=1;
}
```